# What does the "FG" in the formal name of the Symphogear system stand for?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

The formal name of the Symphogear system is 「FG式回天特機装束」, which translates roughly as "FG-Type Sky-Returning Specialized Garment". (Maybe? I probably screwed something up, but this is close enough for the purposes of this question)

What does the "FG" in there stand for?

Comment: Even on the official website, it's only mentioned in passing in the definition of Symphogear.

Comment: 回天 roughly means "reverse destiny/change the tides" (i.e. changing the situation around), amongst [other things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiten).

Comment: I speculate that it might stand for 非公式, but I have nothing soild to back up my claim.

Answer (score 1):

In the manga translator's (http://symphogear.blogspot.com) commentary, the FG is guessed to stand for Fonic Gain (it should be Phonic Gain). However, I'd speculate that it would mean Phonic Gear as it is the more elegant and title-consistent explanation.

As we know, Symphogear could mean Symphonic Gear while Symphonic itself means (etymologically) "Sounding Together/Concomittant Sound" due to the syn- prefix means "together/with" or "concommitant"

ref: [image: The first page of TL commentary]

Comment: Manga translator? Which manga translator? Where? How can *we* be sure?

Comment: @кяαzєя I think his sources are... not licensed.

Comment: "Fonic Gain" sounds very plausible to me (alas...). I'm going to hold off on accepting for a bit, though, in hopes that XDU provides some additional information on this topic. (@Mindwin Unlicensed, yes, but from an accuracy standpoint the translator in question has proven to be competent and well-informed.)